# How is Infinitesimal coordinate transformation related to Lie derivatives?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, tensor-calculus, differentiation, variational-calculus

I am reading the book "Gravitaion and Cosmology" by S. Weinberg. In section 10.9, while discussing Lie derivatives of tensors of different ranks, he makes a general comment:

> *The effect of an infinitesimal coordinate transformation on any tensor $T$ is that the new tensor equals the old tensor at the same coordinate point, plus the Lie derivative of the tensor.*

Is there a straightforward way to see this?

Comment: Consider vector fields as the generators of diffeomorphisms. The Lie derivative is the induced representation of the generators.

Comment: Note lie derivative is only defined for (n, 0) and (0, n) tensors.

Comment: Maybe say something about the context of the quote, im guessing by infinite small coordinate transformation he means infinite small step along the flow generated by a vector field